# how to some up every 3 rows of particular user

Tags: oracle

i have table called `agentsMothlyReport` in this i will get data like this

```
user_id      `year_month` no.of.tikts
iciseva00031    201706  8
iciseva00031    201705  22
iciseva00031    201704  29
iciseva00031    201703  30
iciseva00031    201702  26
iciseva00031    201701  14
iciseva00031    201612  14
iciseva00031    201611  14
iciseva00031    201610  34
iciseva00031    201609  25
iciseva00031    201608  109
iciseva00031    201607  11
```

i want to sum up every 3 rows of particular user,
i have done something like this

```
select sum(no_fo_tickets)from AGENTWISEMONTHLYREPORT where user_id='iciseva00001' GROUP by user_id ;
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Calculate a quarterly field. it would equal YYYY + decode('01', '1', '02','1', '03', '1', '04', ... '12','4'). Then group by the calculated field.

Comment: thank you for the reply @ Robert Jacobs , i did not get what you said can you please provide me a demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(no_fo_tickets)from AGENTWISEMONTHLYREPORT where
user_id='iciseva00001' GROUP by user_id, substr(decode(year_month,1,4) ||
decode( substr(year_month,5,2), '01', '1', '02', 1, '03', '1', '04', '2',
   '05', '2', '06', '2', '07' ,'3', '08', '3', '09', '3', '10', '4', '11' , '4', 
   '12', '4');
```

Comment: it does not work for me     ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 42

Comment: Fixed function name substr.